# Creating a list of .Include() in linq to entities

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a long list of includes:

```
.Include("x")
.Include("y")
.Include("z")
.Include("z.w")
.Include("z.v")
```

I would like to use this list on three different queries. How can I put these in a list and use that list in all my queries in order to not repeat myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
public static class MyQueryHelpers
{
    public static ObjectQuery<Foo> MyIncludes(this ObjectQuery<Foo> query)
    {
        return query.Include("x")
                    .Include("y")
                    .Include("z")
                    .Include("z.w")
                    .Include("z.v");
    }
}
```

Now use it:

```
var q = from f in Context.Foos.MyIncludes()
        select f;
```